# MahApps Metro - Applying transition to tab control

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, mahapps.metro

In MahApps Metro source code, the sample solution includes a Visual Studio style demo application.

[image]

I need to combine the Visual Studio style with AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.
I have modified the XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="VsTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
```

To:

```
<Style x:Key="VsTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type AnimatedSingleRowTabControl}">
```

After the modification the transition worked as expected, but the Visual studio style was gone.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: May be you need to refine Mahapps/Metro source code.

Comment: Tried, but no success. May be I missed something.

Comment: Keep the demo app style as it is and, in `VSDemo.xaml`, simply replace `TabControl` with either `MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl` or `MetroAnimatedTabControl`.

Comment: @jstreet I have tried your suggestion, but no success :(.

Comment: What exactly does "no success" mean? It worked just fine for me...

Comment: @jstreet As you suggested, I have downloaded the latest Sample source code of MahApps Metro and changed the code in VsDemo.xaml  `<TabControl Margin="0,10,0,0">` to  `<MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl Margin="0,10,0,0">`. But I cannot see the transitions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source of MahApps, you should navigate in the MahApps.Metro project to Styles/VS/TabControl.xaml.

To add the animations to this `TabControl`, modify the source like this:

1. Open *MahApps.Metro/Styles/VS/TabControl.xaml*
2. Add the following things to the first `ResourceDictionary`:

   - *xmlns:Behaviours="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Behaviours"*
   - *xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls"*
3. Scroll down until you see `<Setter Property="Template">`
4. Add `<Setter Property="Controls:TabControlHelper.Transition" Value="Left" />` above the Template
5. Replace the `Template` with the `Template` already written in the `MetroAnimatedTabControl` and remove all the background properties. Also change `TargetType` from `Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl` to just a regular `TabControl`

The full source of the VS/TabControl.xaml can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Ssbxg41a

[image: GIF :D]